# Terminology for citizen (minor) with 'alien' parents

Tags: citizenship

Assume a child was born in the US to foreign national parents.  The child remains in the US with relatives in Florida.  The child is to be insured: is there a concise term to communicate the notion that although the child is American by birth, the parents are not?  This notion is necessary to communicate to potential healthcare insurers.

Assume parents are not permanent resident and ‘winter’ in Florida

Comment: Are you talking about health insurance? If the parents aren't in the US, I'm not sure that matters as the relatives will have guardianship of the minor. Are they citizens or permanent residents?

Comment: I've never heard of a formal term for this, and even if there were, it would be fairly obscure and I wouldn't want to count on the reader understanding it correctly.  What's wrong with simply writing "The child's parents are not US citizens and live outside the US"?  And as mkennedy says, what makes you think that it is even relevant?

Comment: Are the relatives in Florida legal guardians of the child? It would probably be a good idea to confer with a Florida family lawyer, preferably one who has some experience with matters implicating immigration law.